# Generate report by cross join between two tables

Tags: mysql, php, pivot, xampp, javascript

I wanted to generate report between two tables by using CROSS JOIN.
Below shows the details of table.

Table 1: kod_jawatan

| jawatan_id | jawatan_kod | jawatan_nama |
| --- | --- | --- |

Table 2: tpermohonan

| mohon_id | pemohon_id | mohon_tarikh | mohon_tarikhluput |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Here's the code that I've tried but it didn't work.

```
SELECT jawatan_nama, MONTHNAME(mohon_tarikh) AS mname,
       count(jawatan_id) AS total
FROM kod_jawatan
CROSS JOIN tpermohonan
WHERE year(mohon_tarikh) = '2019'
GROUP BY MONTH(mohon_tarikh)

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Jumlah',
       count(jawatan_id) AS total
FROM tpermohonan
CROSS JOIN kod_jawatan
WHERE year(mohon_tarikh) = '2019'

This is the output that I want:
```

| Bil | Jawatan | Jan | Feb | March | April | May | June | July | August | September | Oct | Nov | Dec | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

How do i get the output I want? Much appreciated for your helps.

Comment: One main issue is the number of columns don't match between your `SELECT` clauses in your `UNION` statement, which is a requirement of using the `UNION` statement. I.e. the second `SELECT` statement seems to be missing the `MONTHNAME()` column. Also please remove the `sql-server` tag from your question if you're not referring to Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: PIVOT is not supported by MySQL and cannot be produced by simple UNION and CROSS JOIN. Use conditional aggregation. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bmysql%5d%20pivot

Comment: could i not use pivot?

Comment: Follow the tag I added.  Also search stackoverflow for `[mysql] [pivot-table]`, there are lots of examples.  I don't think `CROSS` is useful; it will be a single `SELECT` with a 12-element `CASE` expression.